# Supported table types: Replication engine for DB2 LUW

Tags: ibm-data-replication

While browsing through the IBM Data Replication documentation for CDC 11.4.0, I stumbled upon the following page which describes the supported table types for DB2 LUW.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.planningadeployment.doc/concepts/udb_supportedtabletypes.html

Are we really serious here that range partitioned tables and MDC tables will no longer be supported?! 
We are currently replicating MDC tables using CDC 10.2.1, which functions perfectly, and is also considering range partitioning some tables in the near future, which as far as I know was supported since CDC 6.5.2.
Is the documentation correct here and if so, which other pieces of core functionality may we expect to lose in future releases?

My quick tests indicate that the replication of “range partitioned” and “mdc” tables is still functioning under CDC version 11.3.3 for DB2 LUW.

So it takes me completely by surprise why the documentation states otherwise.

In fact, corresponding knowledge center pages for earlier releases of CDC do not seem to exist, so this piece of information was explicitly added.
Please let me know when you have feedback from product management, so we know if this functionality is still officially supported or just working because it was not removed from the code.

In the former case, the documentation should certainly be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Range partition for DB2 LUW works with a parameter, as you must be aware to get it working. It appears that MDC was never supported even though it works. These functions have not been productized as such.

It may be that someone decided to tighten up the documentation by explicitly stating that unless a feature is officially supported, it is not supported.

I suggest that you [raise an enhancement request](https://ibmanalytics.ideas.aha.io/) to the effect that these features should be properly supported.

You may also be interested in the [Data Replication roadmap](http://ibm.biz/AnalyticsRoadmaps). CDC is on page 5.